# Jquery Datatables column search for checked checkbox

Tags: jquery, datatables

In my **jQuery datatable** I use a `column().search()` searchbox for every column.

I have one column where each row contains a checkbox.

Now I want to filter the table to display only the rows where the checkbox is checked (or respectively unchecked).

Any ideas how to implement this, or pointers to examples?

Comment: I have used a "text" next to the checkbox with the state e.g. "Enabled" or "Disabled". This works, but looks a bit strange.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you meant sorting the checkbox column for selected and un-selected items .If you already had a  column definition for 'select-checkbox' ,update the property  orderable: true. Please refer this example: https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox.html

Comment: Do you want solution as client side or server side?

Comment: Thanks Aditya, I am not using the select extension. The Checkbox is just a representation of a boolean value in the record.

Comment: jits, at the moment i am using client-side filtering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer:

Use the render function to display the checkbox only if the type is "display" for "search" use the data.

References:
https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers#Data-rendering

Comment: A little late but I am experiencing a similar issue:  [My Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45642860/jquery-datatables-search-column-that-is-a-checkbox/45676134?noredirect=1#45676837).  Anyway your solution can help me?